# To pretend that a mistake was intentionally done so as to save face

Tags: phrases, expressions, popular-refrains

I am looking for a expression, phrase or word that describes a person or behavior that pretends a mistake made was intentionally done so as to save face. 
There is a phrase in my language saying "To pretend that the fall was a technique/stunt". I am looking for an equivalent for this in English.

Comment: What's the original phrase?

Comment: I would say the behavior was a _ruse to save face_. I can't think of anything that would let you get rid of the term saving face.

Comment: @Elian, the original phrase for which I am looking for a translation is something like "To pretend that the fall was a technique/stunt". Ie, a person that fall down try to pretend that it was an act that was intentionally done and is a trick.

Answer (score 1):

Most would simply say that they **meant to do that**.

Comment: In software developpement, we lie and say it's a **feature**.

Comment: @MorganFR It's more like, "It's not a **bug**, it's a **feature**."

Answer (score 0):

***[Play innocent](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+innocent)*** is close to what you are looking for.

> - to pretend to be innocent and not concerned.
>
>   - *I know you broke the lamp! John is playing innocent, and he knows more than he is telling us.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.)

Comment: *Play innocent* means to pretend you didn't have anything to do with it, while what the OP wants is a phrase meaning "to pretend you did it on purpose."

Answer (score 0):

[Better to be lucky than good](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46703/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-it-s-better-to-be-lucky-than-good-how-popular-is) can be used in a self-depreciating way by a victor to claim their victory was due to fate rather than pointing out the skillful exploit of an opponent's error.